# How to manage developing an application with git?

Tags: php, git, version-control, installation, state

I am stuck on this idea.

If I develop an application, let's say a PHP forum or cms.

Most PHP forums and CMS' have these things (plus some) in common:

- They include an installer directory.
- Once installed the installer directory should be delete for security reasons.
- The application will not work correctly (displays message, or simply does not work) until the installer directory is deleted.

Now this makes sense, but I don't quite get how I should manage developing this application and version control.

Currently I have two copies of the application on my system.

One "Clean" copy, that has had nothing done to it.
One "Dev" copy, this copy is installed and is the working copy.

If I fix a bug, or add a new feature to the dev version, I then manually copy the changes to the clean copy, commit and push.

This is very time consuming, and, not practical in my view.

I do the same process if an application has say, extensions, I have my "dev" copy installed with the plugin, and I have a clean copy of the extension.

Is there a better way of managing this?

Comment: Don't use copies, use branches ^^

Comment: From what i understand you got 2 questions 1- How to deal with the installer ? 2- How to propagate changes between the Clean and Dev branch. For the second one you can use : git cherry-pick [hashOfYourCommit] to basically commit the same stuff to your clean branch if you dont want to perform a git merge

Comment: The question is basically, how can I manage developing an application when I need the committed version to be in a clean, uninstalled (aka different to the copy I am working with).

Comment: Also if you need to switch your local branch but you're in the middle of something: `git stash` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Commit all changes and bugfixes to the `dev` (`develop`) branch; and only merge from `develop` to `clean` (`master`) when you want to release a series of changes. Use other branches for developing specific new functionality; and use tagging to show release quality code

Comment: So basically only selectively push the changes out to develop (as opposed to just using `git add .`) ?

Answer (score 1):

A typical enterprise workflow looks something like this (there are of course infinite variations):

`production` branch contains all code which has actually been released.  Tags are used to mark specific releases or versions.

A `staging` (or possibly `qa`; the names are fairly arbitrary) branch is used to prepare new releases and/or patches.  So if there is development going on but an urgent patch is needed it can be made in this branch then merged into `production` (`git merge staging`) as part of the deployment or release procedure.

Various `development` branches track specific development effort.  New features, etc.  When they're ready for launch they get merged into `staging` / `qa` etc. until they are actually released.  If there are more steps in your workflow you could add more branches to the list (production -> staging -> qa -> integration -> testing -> etc) if necessary.

The idea of this workflow is that you can always merge-down safely from `production` -> `staging` -> `development` branches.  You merge in the reverse direction when you want to advance some code toward launch.

Branching in git is cheap so you can branch even for simple bugfixes if you like.  You can `git branch` from `production` if your `staging` branch is busy, essentially making a temporary mini-`staging` for your emergency bugfix, merge this new branch to `production` when done and then merge `production` back into your normal `staging` branch.  Just delete the temporary branches when you're done with them.

One situation that comes up sometimes is: you want to do an emergency patch but you're in the middle of development and you don't want to make a new clone and check out `staging` on it.  In that case you can use `git stash` to save your work then checkout the branch you want, fix the bug, then go back to `development` branch and `git stash pop` to get the last stash and resume your work.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the install folder for testing, then mark deleted files with:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [list of filenames]
```

and git will not prompt you to remove them from the repository.

You can use:

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

To list all the deleted files, so you can automate removing them with:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged `git ls-files --deleted`
```

Answer (score 0):

git makes it easy to switch between different versions of your code, so you technically don't need multiple copies. You can create a `dev` branch that has all the messy commits while you are developing. You can even create branches which are specialized to specific bug features or feature implementations. When you are finished to some stable state, then you can merge the branch into the `master` branch. Then whenever you need the "clean copy", you can just checkout the `master` branch. If you do want a separate clean copy, you can simply clone the repo from which you are working or push your master branch from a local repo to a remote one.